# Rest APIs available for IBM DOORS NG similar to Azure Devops Rest APIs?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, rest, ibm-doors

We will be doing an evaluation of a suitable ALM tool for our project and the management is keen on IBM DOORS Next Generation. Currently, We already use Azure Devops for Devops, Testing and Automation testing Integration with TestComplete.

Since we work in regulated Industry, We are also writing some custom tools using Azure Devops Rest API and C# to generate traceability matrix, Test reports etc. that are mandatory and the Rest API documentation from Microsoft is really good for this purpose.

I would like to know if there are similar capabilities in IBM DOORS NG to automate the reporting based on custom templates etc. I tried searching in the net but could not find much information yet. So, any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check out below APIs to integrate with DNG

[OSLC RM V2 API](https://jazz.net/library/article/1197) : the open standard way to programmatically integrate with DOORS Next Generation

[Reportable REST API](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/DNGReportableRestAPI): for reporting purposes, only reading artifacts

[TRS 2.0](http://open-services.net/wiki/core/TrackedResourceSet-2.0/) - the OSLC Tracked Resource Set open standard REST API

[Client side extension capability](https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Main/RMExtensionsMain)

Check [here](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/238288/doors-nextgeneration-apis) for more information.